# Who is YHWH for the people Israel and is he Jesus?

Tags: trinity

**The Question**

Who is *YHWH* in Isa 44:6, 53:3 and Psalm 2:7?

---

My question is to be understood from the perspective of Pentacostal Churches.

***I updated my question***

Please tell me in the comments if you think my question should be moved to SE Christianity and justify your point of view, thank you!

---

Is *YHWH* only

- God the father
- the Holy Spirit
- Jesus Chris

or is he even

- the triune God ?

Isa 44:6 [Amplified Version Bible]

> For *YHWH*, the king of Israel and it‘s redeemer, *YHWH* the lord of hosts says this,
>   ‘I am the first and I am the Last; And there is no God besides me.'

From my point of view Isa 44:6 indicates that *YHWH* is Jesus Christ, because the latter is the redeemer of Israel and „I am the first and the Last“ resembles Rev 22:13, where Jesus Christ attributes himself „the first and the last“.

Psalm 2 [Amplified Version Bible]

> I will declare the decree of the LORD: He said to Me ‚You are my Son; This day I have begotten you. Psalm 2:7

But in Psalm 2 *YHWH* tells „his annointed“ (talking prophetically about Jesus Christ), that the speaker (which is *YHWH*) has fathered Jesus Christ. Which indicates that *YHWH* is God the father.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Theology questions need to be asked at [christianity.se] instead.

Comment: This question is a valid question as it DOES have a specific Bible passage to analyse.

Answer (score 2):

Psalm 2 simply establishes (quite importantly) that "God the Father" is YHWH.  The same can be said for Isa 63:16.  There is little debate about this.  The source of most debate is whether Jesus is also YHWH or not.  I will list three lines of evidence for this.

**Jesus is God in the fullest sense.**

We find in Isa Isa 44:6, 45:5, 6, Deut 4:35, 6:4, etc. that the Bible stridently and repeatedly claims that there is only one God and that God is YHWH.  Further, the NT then explicitly claims that Jesus is God and so must be YHWH.

- John 1:1, “In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God”.  (Compare v14 where the Word became flesh and dwelt among us, thus identifying the Word as Jesus.)
- John 1:18, “…but God the one and only who is at the Father’s side has made him known”
- John 5:17, 18, “In his defence, Jesus said, ‘My Father is always at his work to this very day, and I too am working.’  For this reason they tried all the more to kill him; not only was he breaking the Sabbath, but he was calling God his own Father, making him equal to God.”
- John 20:28, “Thomas said to him, ‘My Lord and my God.’”
- Rom 9:5, “…Messiah, who is God over all, forever praised! Amen.”
- Phil 2:5-8, “…Jesus Christ: who, being in very nature God…”
- Titus 2:13, “…our great God and Saviour, Jesus Christ.”
- Heb 1:8, “About the Son he says, ‘Your throne, O God, will last forever’”.
- 2 Peter 1:1, “…righteousness of our God and Saviour, Jesus Christ.”

**Implicit Declarations of Jesus' Divinity**

One of the frequent habits of the NT is ascribe exclusive titles and attributes of YHWH to Jesus thus making Jesus both God and YHWH.

- Creator: Isa 44:24, 45:18; vs John 1:3, Col 1:16, 17.
- Saviour: Isa 43:3,11, 45:17,21; vs Matt 1:21; Acts 4:12; 2 Tim 1:10; Tit 2:13; 2 Pet 1:1, 11.
- Glory: Isa 42:8, 48:11; vs John 17:5, 24.
- Rock: Isa 44:8; Deut 32:3,4,15; Ps 92:15; vs 1 Cor 10:4; Matt 16:18
- Shepherd: Psalm 23:1; Eze 34:11ff; vs John 10:11-16; Heb 13:20; 1 Peter 2:25, 5:4; Rev 7:17.
- First and Last: Isa 41:4, 44:6; vs Rev 1:17, 18, 22:13.
- Venerable: Ex 20:3, 34:14; Deut 8:19; 2 Kings 17:35-38; vs Matt 28:17; Luke 24:52; John 9:38; Rom 10:9, Heb 1:5, 6, Phil 2:10.

**Old Testament Quotes Applied to Jesus**

The New Testament writers often took Old Testament passages discussing YHWH and applied them or attributed them to Jesus.  Here are a few examples.

- Deut 32:43 (LXX); vs Heb 1:6
- Ps 45:6, 7; vs Heb 1:8, 9
- Ps 102:25 - 27; vs Heb 1:10 - 12.
- Ps 22:22; vs Heb 2:12
- Isa 8:17; vs Heb 2:13

**I AM**

In the Old Testament, Jehovah’s self-proclaimed title of “I AM” is given special prominence in Ex 3:13-15.  While we are told “I Am” was to be God’s name forever, there is no record in the Bible of it ever being used again unless we admit the grammatical connection between “I am” and the “Tetragrammaton”, YHWH, commonly translated, “Jehovah”, “Yahweh”, “LORD”, or even “Eternal” in Moffatt’s version.

The exact phrase “ego eimi” occurs 48 times in the New Testament.  It also occurs 11 times as “eimi ego” which has a very similar but still different construction and all are relational or predicative.  It occurs in a few other forms such as “ego gar eimi”, “ego men eimi”, “ego ouk eimi” (I am not), etc, a total of 75 times (one or two are disputed).  Of the 48 cases of the exact phrase “ego eimi”, “I am”, just 15 have the syntactical form existence as opposed to identification, relationship or predication.  All are listed below (my translation) unless preceded by “not”, eg, Matt 26:22, 25, plus one exception to be noted.

- Matt 14:27, Mark 6:50 – “Be encouraged.  I am.”  [To the frightened disciples in the boat.]
- Mark 13:6, Luke 21:8 – “Many will come in my name saying, ‘I am’”.
- Mark 14:62, Luke 22:70 – “Jesus replied, ‘I am’”.  [He was then accused of blasphemy by the Jews and condemned.]
- John 4:26 – “Then Jesus said, ‘I am.’”  [To the Samaritan woman at the well.  There is a reasonable case for this being identification, but that is a matter of taste.]
- John 6:20 – “But then [Jesus] said to them, ‘I am.  Fear not.’”  [To the frightened disciples in the boat.]
- John 8:24 – “If you do not trust/believe that I am, you will die in your sins.”
- John 8:28 – “When you will lift up the Son of Man, then you will trust/know that I am.”
- John 8:58 – “Truly, truly, I say to you; before Abraham existed, I am.”  [The Jews then tried to stone Him for blasphemy.]
- John 9:9 – “Some were saying that, ‘this is [that one]’, and others were saying ‘no, it is like him.’  But he was saying, ‘I am [that one].’” (This instance is clearly identification rather than existence.)
- John 13:19 – “From now [on] I tell you before the occurrence, that you may believe when it occurs that, I am.”
- John 18: 5, 6, 8 – “He said to them, ‘I am.’ …Therefore, when He told them, ‘I am’, they fell backward to the ground.”  [This occurred when the Jews tried to arrest Jesus in the garden.  It could be reasonably argued that this is a case of identification.  However, the fact that the arresting mob fell backward suggests that much more is intended here.]

It is interesting that, according to Mark 13:6 and Luke 21:8, one of the distinguishing characteristics of false christs is their claim to be “I AM”.  Unfortunately, there has been a historical parade of charlatans making such false claims.

Thus, with the obvious and rather trivial exception of John 9:9 (and self-exclusory Mark 13:6 and Luke 21:8), all of the “I am” existence statements in the New Testament, including the 7 in John, were spoken exclusively by Jesus, and all were either the basis for absolute trust/belief and reassurance in Jesus, or were a clear declaration of His claim to be the “I AM.”

Thus, Jesus is also YHWH as well as God the Father.

**Holy Spirit**

A similar analysis to the above shows that the Holy Spirit is also YHWH.  The Bible assumes that the Holy Spirit is divine in many instances.

- Compare Isa 63:10 with Num 14:11 & Deut 32:12 – The Holy Spirit spurned/grieved is equivalent to God being grieved
- 2 Sam 23:2, 3 makes clear that the Holy Spirit speaking is the voice of God
- 1 Cor 3:16, 17, 6:19, 20 – the indwelling Holy Spirit is a divine presence
- 1 Cor 12:11, 28 – the Holy Spirit distributing gifts is equivalent to the will of God
- The Holy Spirit is essential to the plan of salvation through washing/rebirth (Tit 3:4-6, 1 Peter 1:2), giving spiritual life (Rom 8:2, 9, 11)
- The Holy Spirit is the agent of Scriptural inspiration (Acts 28:25-27, 2 Peter 1:21, 2 Tim 3:16, 17)

We should also note that the Bible affirms all the usual attributes of divinity to the Holy Spirit of being omniscient (1 Cor 2:10, 11), omnipresent (Ps 139:7), eternal (Heb 9:14, cf 1 Tim 6:16), omnipotent (Luke 1:35, Rom 15:19, Zech 4:6), etc.

Thus, we have three persons who are declared to be God (and thus YHWH) and that there is only one God.